# Android Studio Problem with creating a new flutter project

Tags: flutter, android-studio, windows-11

[image]
Can I know why my error popup font is breaking?
When I Run the Flutter Doctor
[image]
this appears, and I understand that I didn't add the directory to the Envir-Path.

But First I want to solve the error notation.

My envir. is Windows11 and using the latest version of Android Studio and also Installed the flutter plugin
also installed Git.

Comment: Yes I added the path til C:\flutter\cmd but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. I uninstalled git and reinstalled it from https://git-scm.com/downloads. However, it still did not fix the problem. Then, I right clicked on Android Studio and clicked on Run as Administrator. Apparently, it fixed my problem.

Also, run flutter doctor in your terminal as it says and install anything you have not installed yet.